# osascript -e command for displaying a text in status bar?

Tags: applescript, ios

[Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW11) has reference to how to display a notification alert but not sure if there is an option to display a message in status bar that can be updated like a price ticker.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to use AppleScript to put something in the menu bar, as far as I can tell, and I looked for a long time.

There are two apps that will put stuff into the menu bar, based on scripts of various kinds:

1. [BitBar](https://getbitbar.com)
2. [TextBar](http://richsomerfield.com/apps/textbar/)

BitBar made a big splash a few years ago, but it's pretty much dead now.

TextBar is less well-known, but it's a much better app, in my opinion, and the developer is very responsive. You can find [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/richie5um/TextBar-Recipes) of the types of things you can do with it.

Comment: I urgently _SUPPORT_ your suggestion! I know (and use) BitBar since a month – _GREAT_ examples ! I was looking for a way to display the # of desktop I'm "on". . . . This is the _VERY_ simple bash script: `osascript /Users/myName/.config/bitbar/Workingspace_Desktop.app` which calls a short Applescript that just gets the name of my BG picture, compares it to a list and "return"s a result that I "formatted" IN the AS like: `[ 3 ]` . . . It is _perfectly doable_ to display changing texts … BitBar's _EXTRA_: by the script's name you specify intervals of execution (mine: 2 seconds) >> so _EASY!_

Answer (score 0):

Macs don't have a status bar; if you mean the menu bar, then no, definitely not. But as you mentioned, it is pretty trivial to use notifications with Scripting Bridge:

`osascript -e 'display notification "All questions have been answered." with title "Alert: Question Answered" subtitle "Notifications could be like a stockticker?" sound name "Ding"'?`

Comment: _"definitely not"_ ?  How sure are you about this ?  I suppose _"definitely"_ implies you're 100% sure, but I wonder _why_ you're so sure of this...?

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong with "definitely not"… see my comment directly at the first answer ! … Whereas "notifications" _ARE_ definitely _NOT_ what the OP asks for: you _CANNOT_ have a continuous flow of information, but could only use "banners" – _which would annoy ME_ if they pop up and fade away all the time.